# Date Insert fails through phpMyAdmin SQL Console

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not sure why the following query is not working

```sql
INSERT INTO Cricket_fixture
('season_id', 'league_id', 'fixdate', 'team_one_id', 'team_two_id')
VALUES ('1', '1', '2012-05-13', '8', '3')
```

I have tried :

- various date formats based on searches  2012-05-13, 2012/05/13, 20120513 (with and without quotes);
- also made sure that FK relations are met since the first two columns are FKs but value '1' exists for both and is valid.

I keep on getting the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''season_id', 'league_id', 'fixdate', 'team_one_id', 'team_two_id') VALUES ('1', ' at line 1

**SOLVED** - the issue was that i was using single quotes for column names (its only for values)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the single quotes on the column names.  You might use backquotes, but I never do.

```
INSERT INTO Cricket_fixture (season_id, league_id, fixdate, team_one_id, team_two_id) VALUES ('1', '1', '2012-05-13', '8', '3')
```